# Where is torcc for Tor browser in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tor

I have installed Tor

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

But I cannot find torcc. How can I find it?

Comment: Did you try `locate torcc`?

Comment: there's no `torcc` it's `torrc`

Answer (score 6):

That file is located at `/etc/tor/torrc`.

If that file you are looking for. But it is in `tor` package.

And this package is not in ppa, but in Ubuntu `universe` repository.

You can find where this file is installed by

```
dpkg-query -L tor | grep torrc
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** The package `tor-browser` doesn't contains a `torrc`. The file is in the package `tor`.

---

`tor`is not automatically installed by `tor-browser`

```
% apt-cache rdepends tor-browser
tor-browser
Reverse Depends:
  tor-browser:i386
```

The package tor-browser doesn't contains a torrc:

```
% dpkg-query -L tor-browser     
/.
/opt
/opt/tor-browser-en
/opt/tor-browser-en/tor-browser-linux64-4.5.1_en-US.tar.xz
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/tor-browser-en.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tor-browser
/usr/share/doc/tor-browser/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/tor-browser/copyright
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps/tor-browser-en.png
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/tor-browser-en.sh
```

You have to install `tor`

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

List the package content

```
% dpkg-query -L tor        
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/torify
/usr/bin/tor-resolve
/usr/bin/tor
/usr/bin/tor-gencert
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/tor
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tor
/usr/share/doc/tor/README.privoxy
/usr/share/doc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html
/usr/share/doc/tor/README.polipo
/usr/share/doc/tor/torify.html
/usr/share/doc/tor/tor.html
/usr/share/doc/tor/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/tor/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/tor/copyright
/usr/share/doc/tor/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/tor/tor-gencert.html
/usr/share/doc/tor/tor-resolve.html
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/tor-gencert.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/torify.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tor-resolve.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tor.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/tor
/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc
/usr/sbin
/etc
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/tor
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/cron.weekly/tor
/etc/apparmor.d
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/tor
/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor
/etc/default
/etc/default/tor
/etc/tor
/etc/tor/torrc
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/tor
/usr/share/man/man5/torrc.5.gz
/usr/sbin/tor
```